# nuget pack command ignores PackagePath directive

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-6.0

I have following  packing directives in my .net6 project:

```
<ItemGroup Label="FilesToCopy">
        
        <Content Include="folder\*" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\net6.0\">
            <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
```

When I pack with visual studio GUI, the files are appropriately placed into `lib\net6.0` folder inside the nuget package.

However when I run `nuget pack <proj.csproj>` command from CLI, the files are always placed into "content" folder inside the nuget package.

Is there a way to make sure that `nuget pack` uses `PackagePath` like it should?

Comment: nuget.exe doesn't support msbuild pack. You need to pack with `dotnet pack` instead.